# powershell failing to list AzResourceGroup name in script

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

Pretty green to this powershell thing but I have a script I'm trying to rewrite (for educational purposes) that requires the manual entry of the resourcegroups in AZ into a variable that is then looped (it removes said resource groups).

`$_names = 'dmz-dev-mgmt', 'dmz-dev-container','dmz-dev-governance', 'dmz-dev-global-dns','dmz-dev-automation','dmz-dev-consumption','dmz-dev-network','NetworkWatcherRG'`

I so far have the following

```
az login

Connect-AzAccount -Subscription "DEV Data Platform"

Get-AzResourceGroup |select ResourceGroupName
```

If I run these commands individually in powershell they all run fine, if I run the script itself after doing the `Connect-AzAccount` it fails to then return the `Get-AzResourceGroup`

I wish to return this list via the script to the `$_names` variable

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below to get all the resource group names and then pass it as a variable to other script and use it as per your requirement:

***`getresources.ps1`***

```
function ResourceGroups
{
$rgs=Get-AzResourceGroup 
return $rgs.ResourceGroupName
}
##to display the result if required
foreach ($x in ResourceGroups){
$x
}
```

***`deletegroup.ps1`***

```
Write-Host ("The acquired list of resource group names is as below:")
. .\getresources.ps1;$_names=ResourceGroups
Write-Host ("Starting the Delete operation on the above aquired Resource Groups!!")
foreach($_name in $_names){
$delete= az group delete --name $_name
Write-Host "Resource Group $_name Deleted Successfully!!!"
}
```

**Note :** I have kept both the scripts in one location thats why used this line `. .\getresources.ps1;$_names=ResourceGroups` in the second script if you have kept them in different location then you have to load it using `. .\path\to\script1.ps1;$_names=ResourceGroups`

**Output:**

***After doing `az login` and `connect-azaccount` I ran the scripts as below:***

[image]

[image]
[image]

---

**Single script :**

```
Write-Host ("The acquired list of resource group names is as below:")
$rgs=Get-AzResourceGroup 
$rgs.ResourceGroupName
Write-Host ("Starting the Delete operation on the above aquired Resource Groups!!")
foreach($_name in $rgs.ResourceGroupName){
$delete= az group delete --name $_name
Write-Host "Resource Group $_name Deleted Successfully!!!"
}
```

Comment: Hi, is there a reason this is 2 seperate scripts and not one whole script? I also assume the reason you are calling the script seperately after logging into Azure is because there is no way to make it programmatically login to Azure and get the resource group all together in one pass?

Comment: no specific reason on why using two  scripts . just as you wanted to store it in a variable from one script first and then thought if you want to use like that in the second one to delete the resourcegroup .

Comment: Hi Ansuman, i figured that's the case, So you have to do the AZ Connect and Login outside of running the script?

Comment: Can you give up me as a single script so I can work through it to see how it all works please? Educational exercise :)

Comment: @Lynchie, added the script under single script in answer